# When does Hibernate create aliases for Subcriterias?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Suppose I create a Criteria using Hibernate:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
Criteria rootCriteria = session.createCriteria(entityClass);
```

If I do not set an alias explicitly Hibernate will use `"this"` as an alias (I checked out and it is hardcoded into the `CriteriaImpl` class.

If I create a subcriteria for this one:

```
Criteria subCriteria = rootCriteria.createCriteria(associationPath, CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Hibernate creates an instance of Subcriteria which is an inner class of `CriteriaImpl` and it does not assign an alias to it in the process.

If I run the query however and check my SQL log I can see that Hibernate created an alias for it but only when I ran the query. Since I want to add Restrictions to my query using this `Subcriteria` it would be nice if I had an alias generated for me. Is there a way to make Hibernate generate that alias or I'll have to pass them to the factory methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally createCriteria is used when chaining restrictions without the need to use aliases

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .createCriteria("Items")
        .add(Restrictions.gt("count", 1))
        .add(Restrictions.gt("price", 10))
    .list();
```

will generate

```
SELECT * FROM orders o join items i ON ... WHERE i.count > 1 and i.price > 10
```

with alias it looks like

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .createAlias("Items", "item")
    .add(Restrictions.gt("item.count", 1))
    .add(Restrictions.gt("item.price", 10))
    .list();
```